# Python multiprocessing is seemingly affecting outcome of program

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing

I have a program that should visit each given URL from a set and download the pictures. The original program was slow, so I implemented multiprocessing to speed it up. But now, the new program is not downloading the same pictures as the original program. It almost seems like it's skipping some of the URLs. Could this have to do with the multiprocessing? What if two processes try to save a photo to my computer at the same time? Would it cause problems and potentially ignore one?

Original program without multiprocessing:

```
def accessAndSaveFiles(urlSet, user, verboseFlag):
    for url in urlSet:
        ...
        img_data = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
        open(filePath, 'wb').write(img_data.content)

def main():
    ...
    accessAndSaveFiles(urlSet, user, verboseFlag)
    ...
```

New program with multiprocessing:

```
def accessAndSaveFiles(urlSet, user, verboseFlag):
    with multiprocessing.Pool(os.cpu_count()) as pool:
        pool.starmap(processURL, zip(urlSet, repeat(user), repeat(verboseFlag)))

def processURL(url, user, verboseFlag):
    ...
    img_data = get(url, allow_redirects=True)
    open(filePath, 'wb').write(img_data.content)

def main():
    ...
    accessAndSaveFiles(urlSet, user, verboseFlag)
    ...
```

Thank you for any assistance!

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]? This code obviously doesn't run and has a lot of missing information that could give a clue to the cause.  As long as the processes are writing different, unique files there should be no issue.

Comment: Side note: Use `with` statements with your `open` calls, especially when writing in multiprocessing workers. You might get lucky and not have any reference cycles and CPython will close the open file handles for you, but on non-CPython interpreters, or if you accidentally involve the file object in a reference cycle, without a `with`, the file may not be closed (and therefore may not flush buffers) before the worker cleans up via `os._exit`, which hard terminates the process without cleanup. `with open(filePath, 'wb') as f: f.write(img_data.content)` is only slightly longer, and much safer.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thank you for the advice, I'll change that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not enough information to debug, but you can debug yourself by adding some print statements to see what is being run in each worker.  Example:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from itertools import repeat
import time

def accessAndSaveFiles(urlSet, user, verboseFlag):
    with mp.Pool() as pool:
        pool.starmap(processURL, zip(urlSet, repeat(user), repeat(verboseFlag)))

def processURL(url, user, verboseFlag):
    print(mp.current_process().name,url,user,verboseFlag)
    time.sleep(1) # Simulated work
    print(mp.current_process().name,'done')

def main():
    accessAndSaveFiles('abcdefghijklmnop', 'me', True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
SpawnPoolWorker-2 a me True
SpawnPoolWorker-4 b me True
SpawnPoolWorker-7 c me True
SpawnPoolWorker-1 d me True
SpawnPoolWorker-6 e me True
SpawnPoolWorker-3 f me True
SpawnPoolWorker-5 g me True
SpawnPoolWorker-8 h me True
SpawnPoolWorker-2 done
SpawnPoolWorker-2 i me True
SpawnPoolWorker-4 done
SpawnPoolWorker-4 j me True
SpawnPoolWorker-6 done
SpawnPoolWorker-7 done
SpawnPoolWorker-3 done
SpawnPoolWorker-1 done
SpawnPoolWorker-6 k me True
SpawnPoolWorker-7 l me True
SpawnPoolWorker-3 m me True
SpawnPoolWorker-1 n me True
SpawnPoolWorker-5 done
SpawnPoolWorker-5 o me True
SpawnPoolWorker-8 done
SpawnPoolWorker-8 p me True
SpawnPoolWorker-2 done
SpawnPoolWorker-4 done
SpawnPoolWorker-6 done
SpawnPoolWorker-1 done
SpawnPoolWorker-3 done
SpawnPoolWorker-7 done
SpawnPoolWorker-5 done
SpawnPoolWorker-8 done
```

You can see from this that there are 8 workers in the pool, and see the three parameters passed for each job.  Since there were 16 jobs, as the first 8 complete another job is picked up by the worker until they are all done.